# Hibernate query returns empty list even though values exist in database

Tags: hibernate

I have developed an application using spring mvc and hibernate. A scheduled task updates my database (mysql) every 2 mins with new data, and I retrieve this data by a hibernate query. Noticed the issue that sometimes hibernate returns empty list from the table, and sometimes it fetches the latest values though my database always have values.

This is an issue which came up in production only. 
This is how I call from the javascript,

```
$.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    contentType : "application/json",
    url : "/myapp/getData",
    dataType : 'json',
    timeout : 100000,
    success : function(res) {
        console.log("result: ", res);
        //process data
    },
    error : function(e) {
        console.log("ERROR: ", e);
    },
    done : function(e) {
        console.log("DONE");
    }
});
```

And my java code :

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        Date sDate = new Date();
        SessionFactory factory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        List<Weather> wlist = null;
        Date fDate=getStartOfDay(sDate);
        Date tDate=getEndOfDay(sDate);
        Query query = session.createQuery("from Weather wr WHERE wr.addDate BETWEEN :stDate AND :endDate ORDER BY id desc");
        query.setParameter("stDate", sdf1.parse(sdf1.format(fDate)));
        query.setParameter("endDate", sdf1.parse(sdf1.format(tDate)));
        query.setMaxResults(1);
        wlist = query.list();
        session.clear();
        session.close();
        return wlist;
```

Hibernate mapping:

```
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
               <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</property>
               <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</property> 
               <property name="show_sql">true</property>
               <property name="hibernate.connection.CharSet">utf8</property>
               <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8</property>
               <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property>
               <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
                  com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
               </property>
```

I get the data sometimes and sometimes empty list. Please help.
Is there anything more we need to do for a production setup

Comment: Please add the code for fetch query

Comment: Do you see any exception or error in production logs ?

Comment: Does a raw query on the database not generate records when they should be there?

Comment: Since you are querying the data on the basis of date , please try to execute the query in the database giving the date for which you are getting empty list

Comment: Are you sure stDate is before endDate?

Comment: As an aside, what’s the point in formatting `fDate` and parsing it back immediately? More important, `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` are long outdated. You should prefer to use [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Hibernate should be able to use the classes from there.

Comment: could you please check it out your columns datatype and whether you have used milliseconds overthere as well ? Since you have used milliseconds from your date format that also will be sent to the query param so please check it out.